# How to log an long long value with NSLog?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nslog

How can I do that? What's the format specifier?

For example, I have:

```
long long veryLong = // assume value here
NSLog(@"%f", veryLong); // of course wrong...
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) section of the String Programming Guide for Cocoa is a great bookmark for your browser ... ;-)

Comment: Would the down-voter care to explain? The referenced page contains the answer to this exact question and all related questions for Cocoa (and Cocoa Touch) string formatting in a concise list. It's one of the top links in my own Cocoa-related bookmarks.

Comment: The link provided is the official documentation, but does not contain the answer. Just came from there looking, and had to come here to get the right answer.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi the question is pretty specific and you could just answer it instead of linking to another document that answers it

Answer (score 59):

```
long long veryLong = // assume value here
NSLog(@"My long long is: %lld", veryLong); // now it's right
```

Comment: `%ld` if one long

Answer (score 7):

Try using %lli.

I'd have written simply %lli, but SO doesn't like short answers.

Comment: That goes towards my word count? Cool.

Comment: Not usually cool (excessive hyperlinkage can thwart one's natural propensity toward verbosity), but cool in this case. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need %qi, my friend.

Comment: Can you explain what %qi represents?

Comment: Nevermind, found it: http://www.makebetterthings.com/objective-c/nsstring-format-specifiers/

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way though unnecessary if it's a plain old type and not already an NSNumber, if you convert this to an NSNumber or something similar then the included format method will automatically do the right thing if you just use %@.

Answer (score 0):

int64 / long long int "%lld"
uint_32_t "%u"